# How to change background colour transparent in React-Native checkBox?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

In my scenario, I am trying to implement react native check box for `android` and `iOS` using Reactnative Elements. Here, I need to change checkbox with label background colour. It is showing full white but how to change it is transparent?

https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html

```
<CheckBox
  checkedIcon={<Image source={require('../checked.png')} />}
  uncheckedIcon={<Image source={require('../unchecked.png')} />}
  checked={this.state.checked}
  onPress={() => this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the containerStyle prop (https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html#containerstyle)
The easiest (but also ugliest) way would be to say

```
<CheckBox
  containerStyle ={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
  checkedIcon={<Image source={require('../checked.png')} />}
  uncheckedIcon={<Image source={require('../unchecked.png')} />}
  checked={this.state.checked}
  onPress={() => this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})}
/>
```